# SwiftUI does not load image from Assets

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a bank of images I'm trying to load through an array, but I keep getting the error below

`Fatal error: Couldn't load image Amanda Brady from main bundle.: file /Users/foo/My Projects/Swift/contactsProject/ContactsProject/ContactsProject/Models/Data.swift, line 57`

If I call the image manually the image loads fine

`Image("Amanda Brady")`

Here's the portion of the code I'm using.

```
struct ContactRow: View {
    var contact: Contact

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            contact.image
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Text("\(contact.first_name) \(contact.last_name)")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

```
static func loadImage(name: String) -> CGImage {
    guard
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "png"),
        let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as NSURL, nil),
        let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't load image \(name) from main bundle.")
    }
    return image
}
```

I've checked Build Phases and assets is present

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what your code does, could you fix it and better explain what you tried to do?

Comment: What is contact.image and where do you use loadImage function?

Comment: I went ahead and uploaded the project to github https://github.com/rbevans-ugh/ContactProject